# Align TextViews relative to each other

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have two TextView.
First TextView contains dynamic text, that can be small and big.
Second TextView contains static small text.
Second TextView should be located to right of first TextView.

This is how it should works:

- when first text is big:
  [image]
- and when text is small:
  [image]

How can I make this layout? With Relative or Linear layouts when first TextView contains big text - second text simply disappeared from screen.

Comment: show your code what you have done .xml and java file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  [**`FlexboxLayout`**](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Add the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
}
```

**Usage**

```
 <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:flexWrap="nowrap"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:alignContent="stretch" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff0"
            android:text="niledfdfdfhfgfdgdfgdfgfgfggdfgdfggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggfhssdsdsdsfgdfgfgfgfgfggfgdgdfgfgfgdsddjfhdkjfhjshdf"            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="nilxcvxceshdfhd"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_minWidth="50dp"
            app:layout_minHeight="20dp"
            app:layout_alignSelf="center"

            />

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

**OUTPUT WITH BIG TEXT** [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a LinearLayout with orientation: "horizontal" and add both textviews in it.

```
<LinearLayout
     ...
     android:orientation="horizontal">
   <TextView .../>
   <TextView .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code I think It will work as you want

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="asdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="2asdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```